# What is the proper way to handle MouseOver and MouseOut in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseover, mouseout

This feels like it should be obvious, but I am having trouble handling MouseEnter and MouseOut with a series of movieclips in actionscript.

I have a movieclip that serves as a background.  On that background, I am adding an additional movieclip to serve as a button.  On that button's MouseEnter, I add an additional movieclip to serve as a hoverstate, and remove the initial button.  On MouseOut, I remove the hoverstate button, and readd the original plain button.

90% of the time, it works as you would expect.  But the other 10% of the time, on MouseOut, the MouseEnter event triggers and even though your mouse is not on the button anymore, it has the hoverstate on such that you do.

Some code to illustrate, this is my main movieclip that I add first thing:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Menu_Main extends MovieClip {

    var backdrop:Backdrop;

    public function Menu_Main() {
        backdrop = new Backdrop();
        addChild(backdrop);
    }
}

}
```

And here is my subsequent movieclip logic, the one that handles my menu button:
    package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Backdrop extends MovieClip {

    var button:MyMenuButton;
    var button_hover:MyMenuButton_Over;

    public function InitializeButton()
    {
        button = new MyMenuButton();

        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Button_MouseOver);
        addChild(button);
    }

    function Button_MouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        removeChild(button);

        button_hover = new MyMenuButton_Over();
        button_hover.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, ButtonHover_MouseOut);
        addChild(button_hover);
    }

    function ButtonHover_MouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        removeChild(button_hover);
        addChild(button);
    }

    public function Backdrop() {

        InitializeButton();

    }
}

}
```

The code here does not include my attempts to remove EventListeners in opportune places.  No matter what combination of adding and removing EventListeners, the result would be the same.  I have also tried some combinations of ROLL_OUT and ROLL_OVER instead of the mouse versions.  I can't say that I've used them perfectly, but the results were again the same.

Can anyone give some advice as to the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first, I've tried your code, using Flash CS5.5 and FlashDevelop, and see NO problems that you describe. The button performs well for me (on an old P4 machine).

Second, you can accomplish the same performance with a little less code and one fewer MovieClip.
Make a button MC with two frames. Color the button's body differently in fr. 2 than in fr. 1.

Use same Main class. Backdrop class now looks like this:

```
package
{

 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 public class Backdrop extends MovieClip {

 var button:MyMenuButton;
 var button_hover:MyMenuButton_Over;

public function Backdrop() 
{
   InitializeButton();
}

 public function InitializeButton()
 {
    button = new MyMenuButton();
    button.stop();
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Button_Over);
    addChild(button);
 }

 function Button_Over(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    button.gotoAndStop(2);        
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Button_Out);
 }

 function Button_Out(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
    button.gotoAndStop(1);    
 }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Craig for your example.  It seems to do the trick, except I am getting some flickering effects.  I'll have to see if removing/readding some eventlisteners will do the trick.

Comment: I changed the MOUSE_OUT and MOUSE_OVER events to ROLL_OUT and ROLL_OVER.  This has helped quite a bit.

Comment: You shouldn't have any 'flicker' if you use the code I posted AND you have only ONE button MovieClip with 2 frames. Let me know if you still have 'flicker.'

Comment: After I changed the MOUSE_OUT and MOUSE_OVER events to ROLL_OUT and ROLL_OVER, the flickering stopped.  However, When I mouse over it, the events seem to fire "extra".  One mouse over of course should just trigger one event, but what happens to me seems to be that the OVER triggers, then an OUT, and then another OVER.  I have seen this happen with the way I initially tried to handle this problem too.  Very confusing.

Comment: It seems that some of the flickering is due to the art I am using!  Thanks very much Craig :) Hopefully I can get the rest from here!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because events in Action Script are not synchronous.

Best practice here is to add a single transparent button, on which you will add all the listeners needed - ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT. On each handler - do what you want to do - add or remove children, that doesn't matter, because the actual target which dispatches the events is still there and it's still the same.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried your advice, but ultimately the same effect happens.  Blank button, adding and removing the different button states to that blank button and adding roll_over & roll_out eventlisteners, and the same 10% of the time the roll_out will cause an additional roll_over event.  I must be making this way too difficult.

Comment: I meant to add different button states, and not to do anything with the invisible button - it acts just like a hover area for OTHER button.

What I advise you is to try merging those states into one single button (if possible) and just make gotoAndStop('over'), instead of that complex solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Andrey, I will try to get this resolved one way or another :)